# Error while installing Cyberlink for C++

Tags: c++, build, makefile

I am getting the following error when i try to `make install` [Cyberlink4CC](http://www.cybergarage.org/twiki/bin/view/Main/CyberLinkForCC)

```
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include/cybergarage/io'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  cybergarage/io/BufferedReader.h cybergarage/io/File.h cybergarage/io/FileInputStream.h cybergarage/io/InputStream.h cybergarage/io/InputStreamReader.h cybergarage/io/LineNumberReader.h cybergarage/io/StringBufferInputStream.h cybergarage/io/FileInputStream.h cybergarage/io/Reader.h cybergarage/io/StringReader.h '/usr/local/include/cybergarage/io'
/usr/bin/install: will not overwrite just-created `/usr/local/include/cybergarage/io/FileInputStream.h' with `cybergarage/io/FileInputStream.h'
make[2]: *** [install-nobase_includeHEADERS] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/bernd/tools/cybergarage/CyberLink4CC/include'
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bernd/tools/cybergarage/CyberLink4CC/include'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Can anybody help me with this error?

One more question: the changelog on the [website](http://www.cybergarage.org/twiki/bin/view/Main/CyberLinkForCC#ChangeLog) for Cyberlink4CC says that there are last changes on 2013-01-09 but on [github](https://github.com/cybergarage/CyberLink4CC) the last commit was 2 years ago? is this repository somehow outdated? where can i find the current state of the project?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileInputStream.h is listed on that command line twice. install appears to be balking at that. That appaers to be a makefile error of some sort.

That repository certainly seems to be out of date. The subversion repo however appears to match that changelog.